# Is there a better reference container than a one-element array?

Tags: java

A Java anonymous class can only access a variable from the surrounding method if that variable is `final`, and hence the inner class can't write to that variable. In order to capture an object created by an enclosed type, I've created a `final` single-element array to act as a reference:

```
    final String[] ref = new String[1];
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ref[0] = "Hello world";
        }
    };

    runnable.run();
    System.out.println(ref[0]);
```

This appears to work, and I imagine has good performance. But it feels slightly hacky.

Obviously it is trivial to write a `Ref` class to replace this such that:

```
    final Ref<String> ref = new Ref<>();
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ref.set("Hello world");
        }
    };

    runnable.run();
    System.out.println(ref.get());
```

... is there an existing class in the standard Java runtime that does this?

I've looked at `java.lang.ref.Reference`, and this isn't the same thing. These are immutable, the only implementations are for weak/phantom references.

Comment: They can access fields of the outer class.

Comment: Don't call `Runnable.run()`; use `start()` (if you want another Thread).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch who says I want another thread? There are lots of other use cases for Runnable, and `run()` is its method. The `Runnable` in this example doesn't *have* a `start()`. Regardless, `Runnable` is just a useful example of a single-use anonymous class, here.

Comment: Java 8 collectors and streams very often use a single-element array as a holder variable, if you're looking for precedent.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's [`AtomicReference<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) which is what I'd normally use.

```
final AtomicReference<String> ref = new AtomicReference<String>();
final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ref.set("Hello world");
    }
};

runnable.run();
System.out.println(ref.get());
```

The only downside here is that unless multiple threads are involved, it's *slightly* misleading as `AtomicReference` is usually designed for concurrent access - but as a simple wrapper object, I think it's a nice solution.

Answer (score 5):

Your approach is quite common I think for that specific type of situation.

There is also [AtomicReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) although it is generally used in a multi-threading context.

Or you could use a `Callable<String>` that returns `"Hello World"` instead of a `Runnable`.

Comment: Nowadays, `Supplier<>` is likely a better option than `Callable<>` (unless one specifically needs to support throwing checked exceptions)